# Constant authentication popup for Outlook Web Access using Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, outlook-web-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome not remembering my login details to a Sharepoint site.](https://superuser.com/questions/219683/chrome-not-remembering-my-login-details-to-a-sharepoint-site)

When accessing my company's Outlook Web Access using Chromium 6.0.472.62 on Ubuntu 10.04, I constantly get a popup telling me that "The server [OWA-SERVER]:443 at [OWA-SERVER] requires a username and password.". Additional, the whole browser screen is greyed out so you can't do anything else than enter your credentials or cancel.

If I click on cancel, the popup will appear again after the next action (i.e. page change). If I enter the credentials, I won't be asked again by Chromium (until I close the browser, that is).

Is there any way to not have Chromium ask me for my password for each time? And I mean without installing any Chrome addons.

P.S. 1: Chromium is the open source project on top of which Google Chrome is built (in case you didn't know ;) )

P.S. 2: This does not happen using Firefox on the same machine/OS.